# tshark to filter UDP flows

Tags: linux, networking, wireshark, tshark

I have a scenario in where I have a big chunk PCAP file contains different flows (that share source IP and port, destination IP and source and TCP/UDP).

I am wondering if I can use tshark to split this big pcap file into different pcap files flows. each PCAP file contains a single flow.

I found this code, but it works for TCP connections

for stream in `tshark -r ~/Downloads/http.cap -T fields -e tcp.stream | sort -n | uniq`

do

echo $stream

```
tshark -r ~/Downloads/http.cap -w stream-$stream.cap -R "tcp.stream==$stream"
```

done

I am looking in how to split UDP connections?

Many thanks for your help in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 2):

[SplitCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=SplitCap) is your friend.
SplitCap is an open source pcap file splitter.
By default it splits a pcap into multiple files based on UDP and TCP sessions. The output is one file per session.
$ splitcap -r yourfile.pcap

You can read more tips en trics in my article about [SplitCap and TShark](http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2011/10/splitcap-and-tshark-by-joke-snelders.html)

Answer (score 0):

Splitcap works using the `-y L7` flag but this can also be done with tshark as follows:

```
tshark -r http.cap -T fields -e data | xxd -r -p > out.bin
```

Piping tshark's output to xxd is necessary as the output from tshark is in hex. And you'll probably want to filter by host (using `-R` or `-Y` flags) on tshark so you end up with contiguous data output.